# How to add element to existing JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Part of my code

```
 ArrayList<Item> i = g.getItems(); 
 Vector itemsVector = new Vector(i); 
 JList items = new JList(iemsVector);
```

Later in the code I create new object which I want to add to JList. How can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Populate the JList with a DefaultListModel, not a vector, and have the model visible in the class. Then simply call addElement on the list model to add items to it.

Comment: hmm, but what if you want to make sure you only add one type of object to the JList? This is imperfect.

Comment: @AexMills: You know not what you speak of. DefaultListModel allows for generics, and you would never expose the model directly to the outside world but rather would make it private. Then you'd give the class a public method to allow additions to the model, but the method's parameter (generic or otherwise) would prevent anyone from attempting to add objects of the wrong type.

Answer (score 6):

Well you can not use directly that Array but use this this will might help you for the same.

```
 DefaultListModel demoList = new DefaultListModel();
 demoList.addElement("addElements");
 JList listd = new JList(demoList);
```

That way you can add elemets into the LIST.

Answer (score 3):

You may add it (`new object`) to the `itemsVector` (Vector). After adding an `item` into Vector object invoke the `items.setListData(itemsVector);` method.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the `add` method, like this: `items.add(newItem)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
private javax.swing.JList<String> list1;
list1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));

DefaultListModel listModel1 = new DefaultListModel();

String st="Working hard";
listModel1.addElement(r);

list1.setModel(listModel1);
```

Comment: that `r` should be changed to `st`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using code similar to the following:

```
public void addRow(MyObject object)
{
    Object[] objects = new Object[]{object.getSomeInt(), object.getSomeString()};
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    tableModel.addRow(objects);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(model);

// Initialize the list with items
String[] items = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  model.add(i, items[i]);

}
```

source : [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddingandRemovinganIteminaJListComponent.htm)